# Is it possible to use the Mac Wolf3D sounds on EXCWolf?

Tags: mods, wolfenstein-3d

I purchased Wolfenstein 3D via steam on PC. I have downloaded and installed [ECWOLF](https://maniacsvault.net/ecwolf/download.php).

Is it possible to mod the game to use the sounds from the Mac version?

Comment: I have discovered https://www.moddb.com/mods/macenwolf which has the sounds, but not as part of the .wl6 files.

Comment: And Macenstein https://wl6.fandom.com/wiki/Mac-enstein_(All_Three_Encounters)